# Expander content not visible

Tags: .net, wpf, expander

I wanted to have an expander in my WPF application. It looks something like this.

```
<Expander Header="Know Words" x:Name="expKnownWords" Margin="2,0,2,300" Height="30" IsExpanded="True" ExpandDirection="Down">
            <Expander.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.522"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Expander.Background>
            <StackPanel x:Name="pnlNextWord" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="200" Margin="10,20,10,20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtWord" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Width="200" Margin="30,100,50,100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding WordToShow, Source={StaticResource ReadWordsWindow}}" />
                <Button x:Name="btnShowMeaning" Margin="80,80,50,80" Height="30" Width="190" Visibility="{Binding ShowMeaningButtonVisibility, Source={StaticResource ReadWordsWindow}}" Content="{Binding LblShowMeaning, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtMeaning" Margin="20,100,50,100" Height="130" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding MeaningVisibility}" Text="{Binding MeaningToShow, Source={StaticResource ReadWordsWindow}}"/>
           </StackPanel>   
 </Expander>
```

Within the expander control, I need to have a stack panel which contains 2 textboxes and a button. The problem is that when I run the application nothing is visible under expander and I can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: Because you set `Height` of the `Expander` to 30. On top of that margins on the elements are also part of the problem.

Comment: To tag your question with `c#`, you have to at least show the problem related with `c#`.

Comment: I tried by changing the Height to Auto as well. But it didn't work. Although If I remove the Expander I can see the stack panel properly.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is residing in Margin you set in Expander. Could you please try below code.

```
<Expander Header="Know Words" x:Name="expKnownWords" Margin="2,0,2,0" IsExpanded="True" ExpandDirection="Down">
            <Expander.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.522"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Expander.Background>
            <Expander.Content>
                <StackPanel x:Name="pnlNextWord" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtWord" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Width="200" Margin="10,80,20,80" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Test" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnShowMeaning" Margin="20,80,20,80" Height="30" Width="190" Visibility="Visible" Content="Content"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtMeaning" Margin="20,80,20,80" Height="50" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" Text="Test2"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander.Content>
        </Expander>
```

Comment: Yes, margin and height was the issue. I was able to figure it out after comments from "dkozl". Anyways, thanks for the help.